# How to get the current site url in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio-2012

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow developed in Visual Studio 2012. How can I retrieve the current site url to a local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fount the solution**.. We have to use the 'LookupWorkflowContextProperty' activity. Example show below:

[image]

currentSiteUrl is a local variable.